# Is it possible to generate HTML(5) with Thymeleaf and response with Jax-RS?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

How can I generate HTML5-Code with Thymeleaf send it with Jax-RS? In the example I see only a WebContext.

Big Thx

Comment: stackoverflow is not the thymeleaf support forum, so we don't know what "the example" is. Please add links if you're talking about specific webpages, and please show code to demonstrate what you've tried, and where you think it's not working (note: minimal examples that illustrate the problem you're having, not multi-file programs).

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate almost any template engine with JAX-RS, see the links.

http://bufferings.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/01/03/051649
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/backpaper0/20121231/1356964206

Comment: Only-link answers are not encouraged further if links are not english. If you do understand that content, try to translate and post your own solution adapted for the question itself.